# Workspace pending changes

Tags: tfs, workspace

After checked that there are no pending changes, I have to delete some WorkSpaces linked to a specific user.

I would like to know how I can see the other user's Workspaces.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I resolved the problem with the sidekick tool. i found it very simple and easiest way to resolve what i needed.

Comment: Glad to hear this, just a kindly remind [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) is a useful tool, but it will not support for the newly TFS version such as TFS2017/2018. Besides, you could move this comment with more detail steps to the answer below and mark it. Which would help more people in the community.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT If you know, Are the Sidekick's team working for the support of the newly version of TFS? Or the new TFS version already have implemented similar functions?

Comment: Sidekick is a 3-rd party extension, new TFS version still not implemented similar functions. We encourage users to use tf command to handle  these situation. Sidekick is also using tf command at the bottom. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I resolved the problem with the useful tool Team Foundation Sidekick.
From the Status sidekick application, I was able to view everything linked to a specific user and modified the needful.
Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using [**tf Workspaces Command**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command?view=vsts)

Displays information about workspaces in the system and updates cached information about **a user name** or computer name change on the server that is running Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.

There is an argument ***ownername***. Provides a value to the `/owner` option. Specify "" to match workspaces created by any user.

The following example displays the list of all workspaces for user Peter on all computers that have been created in the following team project collection at the address `http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`.

`c:\projects>tf workspaces /owner:"peter" /computer:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`